# Как в реактивных формах Angular предотвратить ввод определённых символов?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, frontend

Подскажите пример, как реализовать для определённых полей ввод, например только цифр, кириллических символов, либо ограничить по количеству, или только по определённому регулярному выражению.
Валидаторы определяют уже имеющуюся ошибку, а мне нужно как-то предотвратить ввод, если для поля только, скажем 4 символа нужно либо же иное правило.
Я уже думал через декораторы проверку делать и если не проходит, то отклонять, и библиотеки смотрел, но реализовать задуманное пока что не удалось.
Как сделать банальное ограничение ввода символов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа такого?

html:

```html
<input [ngModel]="validValue" (ngModelChange)="onInput($event)">
```

ts:

```
class MyComponent {
    onInput(inputValue: string): void {
        // Не более 4-х символов
        this.value = inputValue.substring(0, 4);
        // Или число
        if (Number.isNumber(+inputValue)) {
            this.value = inputValue;
        } else {
            this.value = '';
        }
    }
}
```